# How are Severity and State in raiserror in T-SQL actually used in practice?

Tags: sql-server

We use `RAISERROR` in SQL Server.  The syntax is `RAISERROR('Some Message.', 16, 1)`.

What is the use of the parameter values `16` and `1` with `RAISERROR()` in my example? I searched the internet and found that these parameters are called `Severity` and `State`.  The documentation tells us some esoteric meanings to these values, but doesn't give us good direction on how to use them or why.

What I want to know is what is meant by `Severity` and `State`?  How should they typically be used?

Comment: This is the documentation on state:

"*state* 
Is an integer from 0 through 255. Negative values default to 1. Values larger than 255 should not be used.

If the same user-defined error is raised at multiple locations, using a unique state number for each location can help find which section of code is raising the errors."

And that's what brought me to this post. So the usage aspect makes it a good question imo.

Answer (score 20):

**Error State** is there to pin point the location where error occured in your code. Say if you have a 1000 lines long stored procedure and you are raising errors in different places, Error state will help you to tell which error was actually raised.

**Error Severity** gives information about the type of error that occured,

upto Severity level 10 are informational messages.

11-16 are considered errors that can be fixed by the user.

17-19 are considered Non-Fatal errors in Sql Server Resources, Engine and other stuff .

20-25 are considered Fatal Error which causes sql server to shut down the process immediately.

Answer (score 4):

According to the docs on [`RAISERROR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql):

> #### Severity
>
> Is the user-defined severity level associated with this message. When using `msg_id` to raise a user-defined message created using sp_addmessage, the severity specified on `RAISERROR` overrides the severity specified in `sp_addmessage`.
>
> Severity levels from 0 through 18 can be specified by any user. Severity levels from 19 through 25 can only be specified by members of the sysadmin fixed server role or users with `ALTER TRACE` permissions. For severity levels from 19 through 25, the `WITH LOG` option is required. Severity levels less than 0 are interpreted as 0. Severity levels greater than 25 are interpreted as 25.
>
> #### State
>
> Is an integer from 0 through 255. Negative values default to 1. Values larger than 255 should not be used.
>
> If the same user-defined error is raised at multiple locations, using a unique state number for each location can help find which section of code is raising the errors.