# What does the state argument represent in THROW statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

The `throw` syntax is

```
THROW [ { error_number | @local_variable },  
        { message | @local_variable },  
        { state | @local_variable } ]   
[ ; ]
```

The [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) describes state as

```
state
Is a constant or variable between 0 and 255 that indicates the state to associate with the message. state is tinyint.
```

I see several examples on internet using value `1` for `state`.

But I am still lost what is it used for. Is it for driving some business logic in calling code but seems like `error_number`argument can be used for that purpose?

Can someone explain with a simple use case/example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23735424/how-are-severity-and-state-in-raiserror-in-t-sql-actually-used-in-practice

Answer (score 4):

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/understanding-database-engine-errors?view=sql-server-2017):

> Some error messages can be raised at multiple points in the code for
>   the Database Engine. For example, an 1105 error can be raised for
>   several different conditions. Each specific condition that raises an
>   error assigns a unique state code.
>
> When you are viewing databases that contain information about known
>   issues, such as the Microsoft Knowledge Base, you can use the state
>   number to determine whether the recorded issue is the same as the
>   error you have encountered. For example, if a Knowledge Base Article
>   describes an 1105 error that has a state of 2 and the 1105 error
>   message you received had a state of 3, the error probably has a
>   different cause than the one reported in the article.
>
> A Microsoft support engineer can also use the state code from an error
>   to find the location in the source code where that error code is being
>   raised. This information might provide additional ideas on how to
>   diagnose the problem.